# How to add a vertex at the center of a face?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, faces

Blender Version : 2.91

I am a beginner to blender and I am referring to this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ltdvd6BQ6nE) and I can't seem to add a vertex to the center of a face in edit mode as he did using the hot key `alt + p` at **2:32**

Is there any other way to do what he did?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Poke Faces* doesn't have anymore shortcut but you can go into the *Face* panel (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>) > *Poke Faces*. You can also right click on the function if you want to give it back a shortcut.

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks It works but as you can see in the video he extrudes the bottom plane using the center of the face as a vertex when I try to extrude, it still works the as it was before **Poking** the face. How can I achieve the sharp point look at the bottom like in the video?

Comment: Never mind I got it, I had to use the ``vertex`` mode first. Sorry my bad. Thank you for the help though

Comment: yes he is in vertex select mode when he moves down the vertex if this is what you want to know  ;)